# Remove chars before first digit in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I need to write a PowerShell script which will remove characters before a digit.
Example: input is "...das.as.1.2.3" or "v.1.2.3"
output should be: "1.2.3"

have zero experience in powershell scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PS C:\> "...das.as.1.2.3" -replace '^\D+'
1.2.3
```

A regular expression to replace anything which is not-a-digit chars, from the beginning of the string.